# MacBook Pro 13" 8,1 shuts down during boot, recovery boot and internet recovery

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, battery, recovery

Laptop: MacBook Pro 8,1 (Late 2011)

List of related (I think) issues:

- shuts down during boot: Apple Logo, progress bar ~10%
- shuts down during recovery boot (Cmd + R): Apple Logo, progress bar ~10%
- shuts down after internet recovery (Cmd + Option + R): sometimes I can see the GUI sometimes not
- charger light behaves oddly: sometimes doesn't turn on and sometimes is working well (can't get the logic)
- after a random shutdown I can restart the Mac only resetting SMC, if I don't reset the SMC the power button is dead

What I did so far:

- changed battery with a new one (side leds are Ok)
- run without battery, same issues
- run without HDD, internet recovery issue
- SMC + PRAM reset
- removed HDD and used a new one with internet recovery, same issues
- run Apple Hardware Test (D) both short and extended mode, no errors in both cases
- changed thermal paste

Booting with Cmd + V:
[image: hangs here then shuts down]

Question: What I can do right now?

My two cents: dying SMC controller?

Comment: Did you've resolved this issue ? My Macbook Pro 13'' has the same problem of yours.

Comment: Hi @RikiRiocma! Unfortunately no, I couldn't figure out what issue I had. Sorry for that, I wish you more luck than me :)

Comment: I finally discovered my issue: the keyboard. For some reason the keyboard stops the boot. If I disconnect the internal flat cable of the keyboard, the Mac boots normally. Amazing.

Comment: Ok @kevin-borghi, I've removed the original keyboard and replaced with a new one, and now the Macbook works again. Maybe be helpful for you or other people having the same issue.

Comment: Hi @RikiRiocma! That's great and really mind blowing, I've to admit that your discover is really interesting. How did you get there? 
Actually I can't test your solution on my Macbook but I'll test asap.

Comment: Hi @Kevin, I've tried to disconnect every cable until the charger light showed the proper behavior.